# Internal implementation of glClearBufferData function

Tags: opengl

How the glClearBufferData is implemented internally? Does it uses CPU (sequential clearing) or GPU (parallel clearing)? If I have big buffer (several megabytes), what is the best way (in terms of time complexity) to clear it? Maybe customized rendering pass, that sets to buffer desired value in fragment shader, would be more efficient? If there is no single solution, please, advise me some materials. Help me please ! :)

Comment: "*in terms of time complexity*" That's not how time complexity works; it doesn't care about CPU or GPU execution or anything of that nature. It's about the complexity of the *algorithm* and how that changes with the number of elements involved. Clearing a buffer N bytes in size is an O(N) operation in terms of time complexity. *Always*.

Comment: Which implementation are you asking about?  [because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865693/1563833)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As with most OpenGL functions, the implementation is provided the freedom to implement it in whatever way it feels is best for the hardware. You aren't permitted to know about those details.

If you need to clear a buffer to a specific value, just call the function and let the implementation do its job.

Comment: Just I need to know if there is some better way to clear big buffer. Maybe there is some common solution that everybody uses. I want to be sure that some approach makes it fast, because of sequential clearing of say 30 megabytes would be too slow.

Comment: @CrazyDev: "*because of sequential clearing of say 30 megabytes would be too slow.*" Why would you think that would be "too slow" or slower than something you could code? The cost of clearing a buffer is in the memory bandwidth available to the process doing the clearing. Equally importantly, why do you think an implementation would use a *worse way* to clear a buffer than you could cobble together? They know their hardware better than you; they know what the fastest way to do a job is. Let the implementation do its job and move on.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll review my point of view :)